# Access SQL Query Optimizing, Slow when adding GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, query-optimization

So, there are two questions I have. One, is whether I'm really doing the right approach for  efficiency? I'm trying to make a new column called Type, spitting out different names depending on if the fields of two tables match. It's a nested IF statement. The query finishes in 2-3 seconds easily, but I wish to GROUP BY the the ItemName and then the Type, since there are a lot of duplicates. After doing that, the query doesn't finish, times out, and claims to be too complicated after 10 minutes of trying. I've also tried using DISTINCT and FIRST without much luck. In the grand scheme of things, I wish to combine this query with others, and creating running sums grouped by Type. So, it is important I can do GROUP BY in this query to get my final query working. Below is the query:

```
SELECT Inventory_All.ItemName, 

IIF(Inventory_All.[ItemName]=Products.[QB Assembly Name], "Assembly Part",
IIF(Inventory_All.[ItemName]=Products.[QB Service Part Name],"Service Part",
IIF(Inventory_All.[ItemName]=Components.[QB Component Name],Components.Type,"Other") )) AS Type

FROM 
(Inventory_All LEFT JOIN Products ON Inventory_All.ItemName=Products.[QB Assembly Name] OR Inventory_All.ItemName=Products.[QB Service Part Name]) LEFT JOIN Components ON Inventory_All.ItemName=Components.[QB Component Name];
```

I read up on other people having similar issues, and I tried indexing, but it didn't seem to help. It seems I need to recreate this query where the GROUP BY function doesn't have to process nearly as much. I'm unsure how this form of SQL and GROUP BY behaves though. Any tips on simplifying the query to let GROUP BY (or a function similar) work?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something on these lines:

```
SELECT Inventory_All.ItemName, Type
FROM (
   SELECT "Assembly Part" As TYPE 
   FROM Inventory_All 
   LEFT JOIN Products ON Inventory_All.ItemName=Products.[QB Assembly Name]
   UNION
   SELECT "Service Part" As TYPE 
   FROM Inventory_All 
   LEFT JOIN Products ON Inventory_All.ItemName=Products.[QB Service Part Name]
   UNION
   SELECT "Other" As TYPE 
   FROM Inventory_All.ItemName=Components.[QB Component Name]) As x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to restructure your query.  Do three separate joins, one for each part.  Then, keep a count by item of each part type -- one column for assembly, one for service, and one for component.

You'll get a result set with the name and a count of occurrences for each type.  Then do what you want with that.

I'm on a mobile device so I can't type the SQL.